# Does cp -p apply to the source or destination file?

Tags: linux, cp

When I use -p to preserve the file permissions of a file being copied, does it apply to the source or the destination file (if it already exists)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's preserves the source file's attributes (mode, ownership, and timestamps) in the destination. (Provided the destination file system supports it.)

If a file already exists it will be overwritten with the source and it's attributes, unless you've combined the -i flag.

Comment: exhausting and 100% correct.

Comment: So if -p is not specified and the destination file exists, the copied file will inherit the mode and owner of the existing file?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. :)